# Excel VBA generating Listbox (defining range)

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, range

Ok, so I'm completely stumped with this. The below was working and now isn't. I'm trying to extract data to fill a list box. when counting rows of my data (which is currently A1:D4) both the row and column count are returning values of '1'. I just can't understand it. The column can simply be 4 as this is not variable, but I need this to count the rows!

```
Sub generateListbox()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\masta p\Desktop\Egencia\Data.xlsx")

Set ws = [Sheet1]

'define end of range

        With ws

        lRow = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lCol = .Cells("1" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'set rng

        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))

MsgBox lRow
MsgBox lCol

MsgBox rng.Address

Me.ListBox1.RowSource = rng.Address

Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Close

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
lRow = .Rows(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = .Cells("1" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

to something like:

```
lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, dataCol).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = .Cells(dataRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

where `dataCol` is the column with the (max?) no of rows you are interested in
and `dataRow` is the row with the (max?) no of cols you are interested in